# Google Analytics - URL builder not linking back to campaigns

Tags: url, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have been trying to use the URL builder to get more insight into how productive our links are. I build the url in the Google builder, and have linked it into emails and our website hyperlinks. However, nothing comes back to the analytics dashboard.

Specifically, I want a URL that I can use in an email campaign that when clicked will tally in our analytics dashboard. I have tried with this builder: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/ but nothing links back to our Acquisition - Campaigns report.

Is there a way that I have to manually link the campaign url to our dashbaord to get it tracked and reported?

Thanks,
learningtheropes

Comment: can u show me an example of your link URL that you embed in emails ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's not a URL builder issue, but a redirect that you have on your website, that "resets" the session and ignores your UTM's.

BTW, try using this extension instead
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-url-buil/gaidpiakchgkapdgbnoglpnbccdepnpk